Fixed-point method function doesn't show output
I did a function for calculating fixed-point method in numerical but when I run the program there is no output. I just cant see where the problem is and I tried adding a max iteration but still it didn't work or when I tried filling the fxI_values it gave me an Index Error: list index out of range
value for
xl=1
error=0.01

def fixedPoint(xL,error):
    xI=xL
    x0=xI
    
    xI_values=[]
    fxI_values=[]
    calc_error=[]

    while True:

        xI_values.append(xI)
        absError = abs(xI-x0)

       
        xI=fixedPoint_func(xI)
        
        calc_error.append(absError)

        # Check for convergence
        if absError <= error:
            break
        
 # Prepare data for tabulation
    table_data5 = []
    for j in range(len(xI_values)):
        iteration_number = j + 1
        table_data5.append([iteration_number, xI_values[j], fxI_values[j], calc_error[j]])

    # Print table
    headers = ["Iteration", "Xi", "g(Xi)", "Error"]
    print("Fixed Point Method :")
    print()
    print(tabulate(table_data5, headers=headers, floatfmt=".4f"))

    # Print a separator line
    print("-" * 100)
    print()  # Print an empty line for spacing

    return xI_values[-1]

# Fixed Point Function
def fixedPoint_func(x):
    return 3/x

# Call the fixedPoint method
last_FxN = fixedPoint(xL,error)


You never append anything to fxI_values so it remains a blank list, so it's shorter than your other lists which is causing the IndexError.

The fixedPoint() function is defined but it is never called.  You must have some other code to call this function -- please show that also.

How to debug small programs.

This code is a working example.
from tabulate import tabulate
from math import cos

def fixedPoint(xL,error):
    xI=xL
    x0=xI
    
    xI_values=[]
    fxI_values=[]
    calc_error=[]

    while len(xI_values) < 20:

        xI_values.append(xI)

        x0 = xI
        xI=fixedPoint_func(xI)
        absError = abs(xI-x0)
        fxI_values.append(xI)
        calc_error.append(absError)

        # Check for convergence
        if absError <= error:
            break
        
 # Prepare data for tabulation
    table_data5 = []
    for j in range(len(xI_values)):
        iteration_number = j + 1
        table_data5.append([iteration_number, xI_values[j], fxI_values[j], calc_error[j]])

    # Print table
    headers = ["Iteration", "Xi", "g(Xi)", "Error"]
    print("Fixed Point Method :")
    print()
    print(tabulate(table_data5, headers=headers, floatfmt=".4f"))

    # Print a separator line
    print("-" * 100)
    print()  # Print an empty line for spacing

    return xI_values[-1]

# Fixed Point Function
def fixedPoint_func(x):
#    return 3/x
    return cos(x)

xL = 1
error = 0.01
# Call the fixedPoint method
last_FxN = fixedPoint(xL,error)
print(last_FxN)

I've made a few changes

Add import statement for tabulate function
Add an import for cos function, I'll explain why below
Move the initilisation of xL and error to near the end, not important
Change the while loop to while len(xI_values) < 20: to ensure it always terminates
Store the current value of xI in x0
Add the line fxI_values.append(xI) to store the result of the function. This is the missing line causing the error
Change the fixed point function to one known to converge

The initial error was caused by the line
table_data5.append([iteration_number, xI_values[j], fxI_values[j], calc_error[j]])

The problem being that fxI_values is an empty list, so trying to find the value at position j fails. Adding a line in the loop
fxI_values.append(xI)

fixes this, but you need to watch the order of when things are stored.
When I fixed this and then ran the code it then got stuck in an endless loop. This is because the function x' = 3/x, never converges. Starting with x=1, it goes 3, 1, 3, 1, 3 ...
changing the while statement so it always halts after 20 iterations prevents the endless loop.
I've also changed the function that will converge.
# Fixed Point Function
def fixedPoint_func(x):
    return cos(x)

This might not be what you want, if you want to see how many iterations it takes to get back to the starting point, you will need to remove the x0 = xI line.

Issue
Do you call the function?
When I call the function it shows me this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deepesh/Development/public/hackthon/graph-e-ton/mr_omd/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    fixedPoint(1, 0.001)
  File "/home/deepesh/Development/public/hackthon/graph-e-ton/mr_omd/main.py", line 30, in fixedPoint
    table_data5.append([iteration_number, xI_values[j], fxI_values[j], calc_error[j]])
IndexError: list index out of range


Recreate Code
import math

def function(x):
    return math.cos(x) - 3 * x + 1

def gfunction(x):
    return (1 + math.cos(x)) / 3
    
def fixed_point(x, error):
    step = 0
    x0 = x
    print("Step \t x0 \t\t f(x0) \t\t x1 \t\t f(x1)")
    
    while True:
        x1 = gfunction(x0)
        step += 1
        print(f"{step} \t {x0} \t {function(x0)} \t {x1} \t {function(x1)}")
        
        if abs(function(x1)) < error:
            print(f"Root is: {x1}")
            return
        
        x0 = x1



error = float(input("Enter allowed error : "))
x0 = float(input("Enter initial guess: "))
    
# Calling the function    
fixed_point(x0, error)


Inspiration of Recreate Code
Here is how I can assist you better: please let me know if the solution provided is helpful. If not, please describe your issue in the comments and let me know what you are expecting as output.

Helpful but, you are using different variables than mine and I add them to a table so if you could use tabulate and same variables name it would be much easier. Also, I just realized I didn't add a g(x) function so where should I add it in my code.
